# Anaylsis of my game

Tags: analysis

Me and one of my colleagues have started playing chess for a while. We are playing one or two matches every weekday, and play tactics over our phones when off work.

Here is one of our latest games. I tried to analyse the game using SCID & Stockfish, but I don't know exactly how to analyse. I think black (my opponent) made 3 major mistakes, and white (me) moved the very first pawn twice (which is bad) and missed an early mate.

Apart from those, what can you tell us novice players about this game?

```
[fen "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1"]
[Event "Lunch Break"]
[Site "Istanbul, TUR"]
[Date "2016.04.20"]
[Time "15:45:00"]
[White "Sadullah"]
[Black "Serkan"]
[Result "1-0"]

1.e4 c5 2.e5 e6 3.f4 Ne7 4.Nc3 Nf5 5.Nf3 d5 6.exd6 Qxd6 7.Bb5+ Bd7 8.Ne4 Qxf4 9.d3 Ne3 10.Bxd7+ Nxd7 11.Qe2 Ne5 12.Bxe3 Nxf3+ 13.gxf3 Qh4+ 14.Bf2 Qe7 15.Bxc5 Qh4+ 16.Bf2 Qh5 17.O-O-O Rc8 18.Kb1 b6 19.Bg3 Bc5 20.Bd6 Rc6 21.Bxc5 bxc5 22.d4 O-O 23.dxc5 Qe5 24.Qd3 Rb8 25.c3 g6 26.Qd4 Qf5 27.Ka1 Qxf3 28.Nf6+ Kf8 29.Nd7+ Ke7 30.Nxb8 Rd6 31.cxd6+ Kd8 32.d7 f6 33.Qd6 Qb7 34.Qf8+ Kc7 35.d8=Q# 1-0
```

Comment: Go to http://en.lichess.org/paste, paste pgn, import game, and request analysis.  The Stockfish engine will tell what it thinks are inaccuracies,  mistakes, and blunders and suggest the best variation.

Comment: It's sort of a cool game. Why was it an error, against the Sicilian, to move the very first pawn twice?

Comment: I am not sure, but stockfish dropped expected outcome from +0.40 to -0.1 when i moved the pawn second time :) @thb. I believe because it delayed development of pieces and makes it harder to protect a pawn further in the beginning.

Comment: The pawn on e5 becomes a very easy target for black. Black can develop his pieces to natural squares, and at the same time threaten the pawn on e5, so white needs to waste developing moves to defend it. The score in the line is abysmal, so it's safe to say that it has been practically proven to be bad. One sample line is:
1.e4, c5 2.e5?, Nc6 3.Nf3, Qc7, and white has tried Qe2, but that just obstructs white further. In short, the weakness on e5 is a major backlash of the rash pawn push in the opening.

Comment: I almost feel like going through the opening, but after white has won a piece there isn't very much to analyze, at least not so that it's very useful for someone at OP's level (advanced beginner, ~1100 Elo strength). After the piece is won, it seems like white managed to play reasonably solid chess to convert the advantage.

Answer (score 2):

I will only consider the opening in this rather brief analysis, as after White won a piece, there aren't many noteworthy events left to discuss.

```
1.e4, c5 2.e5?
```

This move is a mistake. It does not develop a piece. I does not really fight for center control in an efficient manner. However, it does make the pawn on e5 weak to attacks, as it's further away from White's side of the board than it was on e4. Black should probably continue with 2...Nc6 to see if White really wants to play f4. However, ...e6 is not a bad move. One may argue about the question-mark, as 2.e5 is objectively speaking fully playable, but I feel that it is appropriate, as it makes White struggle for equality if Black plays for an advantage. This should never be the case for White in the opening - it should be the other way around.

```
2...e6 3.f4
```

A logical continuation after 2.e5. It is reasonable to pre-emptively guard the pawn on e5 before Black decides to attack it. However, f4 is not a move that helps White's piece development.

```
3...Ne7?!
```

While it aims to develop a knight to f5, the same could have been accomplished by 3...Nh6. However, on h6 the knight wouldn't block the bishop on f8. This would have given Black more flexibility in what move to play next. Normally, when White has played e5 followed by f4, and Black already has a pawn on e6, the play ...Nh6 should be seriously considered, as White's bishop on c1 cannot attack it in these scenarios.

```
4.Nc3, Nf5 5.Nf3, d5!
```

I like the ...d5 push. It is very logical, as it fights for center control. The exclamation mark may be superfluous, but the move is not bad. Alternatively, Black could have played 4...Nc6! This develops a knight, and it takes control of an important central square (d4). It also forces White to make a decision. What should White play? On 5.Bb5, it's possible to play ...d5! 6.exd6 e.p., Bd7! (the pawn on d6 isn't going anywhere) and Black has a great position, with all the light pieces having something to do.

```
6.exd6 e.p., Qxd6?
```

This is a fundamental error that beginners seem to make all to often. The queen shouldn't be running around too much in the opening, as it can be easily attacked by the enemy, thus wasting too much time in the opening. What was wrong with the simple reply 6...Bxd6? Nothing was wrong with that move. The bishop

- does just as much as a queen would on d6,
- is less vulnerable to attacks by enemy pieces, as it's less valuable
- paves the way for bringing the king to safety on g8 with castling.

Generally speaking, when you choose between throwing out the queen and developing a light piece in the opening, you should develop the light piece. It's often too early to say where the queen will be useful in the earliest stage of a game. Note that again, 6...Qxd6 is playable technically speaking, but that's besides the point I'm trying to make.

```
7.Bb5+
```

A strong alternative to this move is 7.Nb5! This move immediately punishes Black for playing out the queen too early, as after 7...Qxf4 8.d3!, and Black cannot defend the c7 square in a good way. White will be able to play Nc7+ shortly, picking up the a8 rook. After this reply, the best Black can do is to pull the queen back to either d7 or d8. None of this would have been the case if Black had taken on d6 with the bishop.

```
7...Bd7 8.Ne4? Qxf4 9.d3
```

While it's nice to attack the enemy queen, a whole pawn is not worth it. At least if White really gains very little as compensation for the pawn. Black can calmly reply with 9...Qc7, and White will be a pawn down for very little compensation.

```
9...Ne3??
```

A game-losing blunder. It simply drops a piece for nothing after 10.Bxd7+! After this there isn't much to be done for Black, if White plays reasonably solid chess, which was what happened in the game.

If anybody feels like posting analysis of the entire game, then please do. But I will stop here, as the opening stage was where most of the valuable lessons were to be given in this game, at least from an ~1100 Elo perspective.